# Making Paginator Work with Session Objects in Django

Tags: python, django, session, serialization, paginator

I'm JSON serializing a `QuerySet` before placing it in a `Django` session using the following:

```
request.session['record_list'] = serializers.serialize('json', record_list)
```

This works fine. But then I have to retrieve it from the session during a subsequent request and pass it to Paginator as follows:

```
paginator = Paginator(record_list, 15)
```

Paginator fails to work with this JSON serialized object but does work otherwise before serialization. I tried casting to list and deserialization after retrieving from the session but neither worked.

Comment: Why you want to store queryset in session? Why can't you get it again in other request?

Comment: I can but that would require querying the database again and in this case there is no need to. A form is submitted with parameters and that forms the query. Then all I need to do is to paginate through the results. But in order to do that, I have to store the QuerySet in the session.

Comment: This seems like premature optimisation. Is fetching the queryset in each request really causing unacceptable performance? If you really want help to do this, then you should post the code you tried and the full traceback.

Comment: i doubt storing in session is any faster than db query... what type of session are you using, DB stored likely, so you are still making a call to the database.  Databases are highly optimized and likely would have the result in memory still, so the cost would be minimal.... if you really want to do it this way, you should be able to deserialize back to a queryset